# What do the orange bars in Amazon Music mean?

Tags: user-interface, amazon-music

Amazon Music provides the user with a column showing grey bars in the song list table. Some of these bars are orange. So the UI element kind of gets "filled up" from the left. It feels like they are more filled (orange) on popular songs.

For example the less popular "Prison Song":

[image: "Prison Song" entry at Amazon Music]

And in comparison "Chop Suey!":

[image: "Chop Suey!" at Amazon Music]

Also, it's not the user-rating of the songs since for example the [Prison Song](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B009J621GW) doesn't have any (at the time this question is written)!

Hovering with the mouse over the element doesn't provide you with a tool-tip. Here's [a link](https://music.amazon.de/albums/B009J6214O/B009J6251I/CATALOG/ref=dm_wcp_albm_link_search_c) to an album which illustrates the behavior pretty well. Be aware that you will have to log in to gain access!

The source of the element looks like this:

[image: Source html]

What does this UI element represent? What does it (so, "popularity") exactly mean? Is it for example the download-count, the "views", the ratings or a combination of them etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the source code of the page you will see:

```
<td class="popularity">
   <div class="trackPopularityContainer">
   </div>
</td>
```

It's the popularity of the songs. iTunes has a similar thing.

> The yellow bars you're seeing indicate the popularity of the track. The more yellow bars that are displayed, the more popular the song.

Comment: I've already stated that it's the popularity. However, what does "popularity" mean? Is it how often it has been downloaded, the user-rating, the "views" (so, "listens"^^) etc. Thanks for your answer however!

Comment: I'll wager that "popularity" probably doesn't have a hard definition. It's probably just a combination of number of downloads, clickthroughs, sales, etc., and is just a way to make a comparison between tracks.

Comment: For instance, in [this thread on Amazon's forums](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/forums/ref=cs_hc_g_m_oldest?ie=UTF8&forumID=Fx1SKFFP8U1B6N5&cdThread=TxV5QA7B9VVZAA&cdSort=newest), the only official response is "...the yellow bars you're seeing indicate the popularity of the track. The more yellow bars that are displayed, the more popular the song." So, that's using a word to define it.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably the relative popularity of each song with in the album, as even very less popular albums too have at-least one song with fully filled “Blue bar”

Comment: But what does it mean? How often people listened to it?